# Hide DataColumn when row is empty using ClosedXML

Tags: closedxml

I am using ClosedXML to export to excel which is working fine but I need to hide some columns if rows are empty. I am doing below but it is not working

```
 var dt = new DataTable("Grid"); 
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new[]
            { 
                var dt = new DataTable("Grid");

                dt.Columns.AddRange(new[]
                {
                new DataColumn("Id"),
                new DataColumn("forms"),
                new DataColumn("Number"),
                new DataColumn("Employees"),                 
                }); 
                var test = data.employee.Select(f => f.name); 
                foreach( var h in test)
                {
                foreach(var n in dt.Columns)
                { 
                if( n.lastname==null)
                {
                dt.Columns.Remove("Employees"); 
                }

                }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working by myself.

```
if( n.lastname==null)
            {
                if (dt.Columns.Contains("Employees"))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Remove("Employees");
                }
             
                
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }
```